# git branch out from tags

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a master branch, from which I created my development branch. Once development was done I created tags (i.e v1.0, v2.0, v3.0, and so on).

Now I need to create a bug fix for my release in v1.0.

Initially I created a branch from tag v1.0, checked out that branch, gave a release and created another tag (say v1.1) from that branch. Note that I didnt merge this branch to my master.

I deleted this new branch so now only the tag v1.1 remains.
I want to know what will happen to that tag since it is not yet merged to master.

When using Gitlab when I try to see that tag it doesnt appear. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you delete tag, than it will be deleted.

Comment: No no i am not deleting the tag.i am deleting the branch from which the tag is created but not yet merged to master

Answer (score 3):

You need to specifically push tags so you can see them on github.

Use:

```
git push --tags
```

or

```
git push origin v1.1
```

---

There is also a specific workflow on github to see tags. Click on "releases" and on the "tags" link there.

[More informations here.](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-tags/)

Comment: this everything i have done.In github there is an option "Network" in that it doesn't show my new tag.only the tags created from the master branch are shown

Comment: sorry it's not github..it's gitlab